# Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates

Tags: reactjs

I have A react component which renders a list of items that have been called from an API and set to setOfAllBooks state. Any time I search for the item, setOfAllBooks state is filtered through by the search ternm and the results are held in searchedBooks state. The results of searchedBooks are then passed to Table component and rendered in a list. At this point it works correctly, but when I search for another item it gets clustered in the Table. What I want to do is anytime I search a new Item after I have searched for a previos term I want the list-items in the Table component to be cleared to make way for the new items that have been searched.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css'
import axios from 'axios';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';

var books = []

const getSuggestions = value => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : books.filter(book =>
        book.title.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue);
};

const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.title;

const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
    <div>
        {suggestion.title}
    </div>
);

const Table = ({ data }) => (
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">No. Of Copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(row => 
                <TableRow row={row} />
            )}

        </tbody>
    </table>
)

const TableRow = ({ row }) => (
    <tr class="table-light">
        <th scope="row" key={row.title}>{row.title}</th>
        <td key={row.author}>{row.author}</td>
        <td key={row.isbn}>{row.isbn}</td>
        <td key={row.isbn}>24</td>
    </tr>
)


class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: [],
            setOfAllBooks: [],
            searchedBooks: []
        };

        this.searchBook = this.searchBook.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/api/book/viewAll')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ setOfAllBooks: res.data });
                books = this.state.setOfAllBooks;
                console.log(this.state.setOfAllBooks)
            })
    }


    onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
        this.setState({
            value: newValue
        });
    };

    onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
        this.setState({
          suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
        });
      };

    onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: []
        });
    }

    searchBook(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({value: this.state.value});

        this.state.searchedBooks = this.state.setOfAllBooks.filter(book => book.title == this.state.value);
        this.setState({searchedBook: []})

        console.log(this.state.searchedBook);
    }

    render() {
        const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

        const inputProps = {
            placeholder: 'Enter the name of the book',
            value,
            onChange: this.onChange
        }
        return (
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <Autosuggest
                        suggestions={suggestions}
                        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
                        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
                        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
                        inputProps={inputProps}
                        id="searchFor"
                    />
                    <div className=" form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="searchFor">&nbsp;</label>
                        <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" onClick={this.searchBook}>Search</button>
                    </div>
                    <Table data={this.state.searchedBooks} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

**The results** 
[image]

**The Error**
[image]

Comment: `<TableRow row={row} />` -- it needs a `key` prop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `key` prop to the `TableRow` component as `<TableRow key={row.title} row={row} />`. Remove the `key` where you have right now.

> .... [A good rule of thumb](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys) is that elements inside the `map()` call need `keys`.
>
> ... keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. . [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings).

So, it seems `title` what you used for `key` will still throw warnings, as they are not **uniqe**. If you have `ID` attribute in the `row` object use that. Adding `key` to `TableRow` will remove the first warning, but other warning still be there until `title` doesn't have the **uniq** values across all the data.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.